# How to destroy the first clone of a UI Image using an array every time I press a button in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Here is a line of code that I used inside the void Update() function to make clones of the UI Image `car`.

```
Image c = Instantiate (car, carPos, transform.rotation, transform.parent) as Image;
```

How do I store all the clones to an array and destroy the first one, every time I press a button?

If I use `Destroy(c);` only the clone instantiated at that moment would be destroyed. But I want only the first clone to get destroyed (each time I press the button).

Comment: Use a `List<T>`?

Comment: @Draco18s Could you please give the code?

Comment: SO is not a code writing service, this is a question and answer site.

Comment: @Draco18s Well, people do help other people by providing 2 or 3 lines of codes(if they can) which could probably help the person who asked the question. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You would want to store your images in a FIFO-type collection, such as a `Queue<GameObject>`.  Then, you can add items to the queue like this:

```
queue.Enqueue(c.gameObject);
```

And destroy objects like this:

```
GameObject.Destroy(queue.Dequeue());
```

So, your code would look like this, if the button for destroying images was named `button` in your code:

```
Button button;
Queue<GameObject> queue;

public void Start() {
    Image c = Instantiate (car, carPos, transform.rotation, transform.parent) as Image;
    queue.Enqueue(c.gameObject);
    //Populate the list using the code above.
    button.onClick.AddListener(() => 
        if(queue.Count > 0) { GameObject.Destroy(queue.Dequeue()); }
    });
}
    //This will remove an image from the list and destroy it when the button is clicked.
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks man. This technique will help me. But somehow the clone is not getting destroyed. Is it because the clone is a UI Image and GameObject.Destroy(queue.Dequeue()); works only with  GameObjects?